# How to convert TimeStamp to string to save figures?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, timestamp, save

```
df.index 

DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-25 17:00:00', '2019-01-25 17:01:00',,
               '2019-01-25 17:08:00', '2019-01-25 17:09:00',
               ...
               '2019-02-15 07:44:00', '2019-02-15 07:45:00',
               '2019-02-15 07:52:00', '2019-02-15 07:53:00'],
```

I want to save figures in the loop using plt.savefig and I'm trying to name the figure as the index for that hour of which the plot is. 
I'm looping for everyhour

```
for hour, i in df.groupby('index_hour'):

plt.savefig(hour+'.png',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

```
hour

Timestamp('2019-01-25 17:00:00')
```

Hour is the final name of the .png file that I'm trying to get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `strftime` method of datetime objects:

```py
timestamps = df.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

If you just want the hour, then you can simply get that (as an int) via an attribute of the datetime index:

```py
hours = df.index.hour
```

Refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for information on how to use the datetime string formatting.

Comment: Thanks. however, TypeError: can only perform ops with scalar values. Does this have to do with dtype in savefig function?
j=i.index.hour
plt.savefig(j+'.png')

Comment: @MohammadZeeshan Where are you getting this error? To use the "+" operator there, both variables must be strings since you want a filename. If you're using the second method from my post, make sure you cast it to string with a function like `str(x)`.

Comment: ValueError: fname must be a PathLike or file handle. 
```timestamp = i.index.strftime("%b-%d %H")
plt.savefig(timestamp+'.png')```

Comment: If I read your post correctly then `i` is a dataframe, which means that `i.index.strftime()` returns an index-object (containing strings), which means you'll need to get a single string out of that to actually use in the `savefig` call.

Comment: Yes you're right
```timestamp
Index(['Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17',
       'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17',
       'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17',
……. 'Jan-25 17'],
      dtype='object')```